# How to make the Jump animations using curves smoothly?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, curves

I've been working on an endless runner game using unity 5 engine         studying some examples. I applied jump action to my character. It did work fine     but I wanted it to be bit perfect so I implanted the jump using curves with this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asx0r.png), came across this issue. That is after applying curves for the character controller with some adjustments, now when I jump, the curves starting to adjust the controller after I touched a platform (the ground) which make the jump unrealistic. I did tried to achieve the jump using fixed Update method, since the game is an endless runner which basically updates everything frame by frame it did not work.
How do I achieve a realistic jump? below is what I tried so far.

```
if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        verticalVelocity = -0.5f; //upward thrust / jump height
            if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == locoState) // is character in moving state
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                {
                    verticalVelocity = 18f;
                    anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
                }
            }
            else if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == jumpState) //Is character in jump state
            {
                if (!anim.IsInTransition(0))
                {
                    if (useCurves)
                    {
                        controller.height = anim.GetFloat("ColliderHeight"); //get the controller height using curves
                        controller.center = new Vector3(0f, anim.GetFloat("ColliderY"), 0f); //Get the controller Y axis using the curves (center of chr ctrlr)
                    }

                    anim.SetBool("Jump", false);

                }
    // Applying curves
                Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position + Vector3.up, -Vector3.up);
                RaycastHit hitInfo = new RaycastHit();

                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
                {
                    print(ray.ToString());
                    if (hitInfo.distance > 1.75f)
                    {
                        anim.MatchTarget(hitInfo.point, Quaternion.identity, AvatarTarget.Root, new MatchTargetWeightMask(new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), 0), 0.03f, 0.6f);
                    }
                }    

            }
    }
```

[image: Character jumping at start]
Character jumping at start

[image: Char controller touching the ground]
Char controller touching the ground

[image: Result after touching the ground]
Result after touching the ground

Help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bit  of code that adjusts the controller based on the curves is inside the if statement asking if the character is grounded.

```
if (controller.isGrounded)
{
 ...
}
```

that way it will adjust only when the character is touching the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Does your gameobject has rigidbody ? if not then try to add and make rigidbody to iskinematic because  when you move an object with a collider and without a rigidbody, the complete static collision data needs to be recalculated, which is slow.
Or, may be ,try playing with animation jump frame rate don't make it too small

Comment: Yes I have a rigidbody componenet. Yes I'll try to make the changes and reply as soon as possible.